# Time and space complexities of compression algorithms like LZ4,Snappy ,Zstandard and Deflate

Tags: algorithm, compression, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am looking for time and space complexities of the above stated algorithms but i can't find it on google,I have wasted more than two days without any result.I would be really grateful if you guys would help me out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression#Lossless_compression_benchmarks. The last few paragraphs of that section may be of use.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all O(1) in space and O(*n*) in time, where *n* is the size of the input. They are designed for streaming compression and decompression, where the amount of data that can be run through is infinite, and there is no growth in memory nor super-linear growth in time due to processing more data.

(Deflate is a format, not an algorithm, so my answer there is with regard to the commonly-used implementation of compression to the deflate format, which is zlib.)